# Java reset timertask based on a mouse movement

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, timertask

I have a Java Swing component that prints "hello" every 1 minute.

```
timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new HelloWordTask(), TIME, TIME);
```

However, I want to reset timertask when a user moves mouse.

```
int count = 0;
private CustomMouseAction extends MouseAdapter {
   @Override
   public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
       timer.cancel();
       timer = new Timer();
       timer.schedule(new HelloWordTask(), TIME, TIME);
       System.out.println("moved " + count++);
   }
}
```

Whenever I am moving a mouse, my timer gets rescheduled, which is the expected behaviour. However, it means that new Timer is created for every "bit" of movement. For example, when I move my mouse around 5 cm, ~30 print statements show up.

Is there a way to make the program more efficient? Moreover, would it be possible to somehow "reduce" the mouseMoved detection rate? For example, instead of being called 30 times, can I make it only being called 10 times (I assume if this was possible, there is a small chance to miss refresh chance).

Comment: First, `java.util.Timer` may not be the best solution, you might consider using `java.swing.Timer` instead.  Next, you could have a counter in the `mouseMoved` which only reset the timer when it passed a given threshold - or even a second `Timer` which would trigger the first after a specified delay, but which, will running, would not be reset

Answer (score 0):

Test with different n values until you're satisfied.

```
int count = 0, lastX = 0, lastY = 0, n = 30;
private CustomMouseAction extends MouseAdapter {
   @Override
   public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
       int ix= e.getX();
       int iy= e.getY();
       if (Math.abs(lastX-ix)<n && (Math.abs(lastY-iy)<n) return;
       lastX= ix;
       lastY= iy;
       timer.cancel();
       timer = new Timer();
       timer.schedule(new HelloWordTask(), TIME, TIME);
       System.out.println("moved " + count++);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> For example, when I move my mouse around 5 cm, ~30 print statements show up.

> Is there a way to make the program more efficient?

This is the whole point of event driven programming. The OS generates the event so you know the user is doing something. You can't control how frequently the events are generated. You can only control the processing you do when the event is generated.

> However, it means that new Timer is created for every "bit" of movement.

1. You should not be using a util.Timer. Instead you should be using a `javax.swing.Timer`.
2. Don't keep creating a new `Timer` in the mouseMoved() method. Instead you should create and start the `Timer` when your frame is made visible. Then in the mouseMoved() method you just invoke the `restart()` method of the `Timer`.

See: [Application Acvitity](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/24/application-inactivity/) for a reusable class that you may find helpful.